# Angular. Error Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addFormGroup')

Tags: angular, forms, parent-child

I have a component with a form:

```
<form [formGroup]="Nsfg.invoiceFormGroup">
   <div formGroupName="namespace">
      <div class="accordion" id="accordionTrikititta">
         <newFacturaE></newFacturaE>
                  
         <fileHeaderComponent [invoiceFormGroup]="Nsfg.invoiceFormGroup">
         </fileHeaderComponent>
         ...
```

As my form grows I need to split it in different components: First one 'fileHeaderComponent'

In my child component I have in the Html:

```
<div formGroupName="FileHeader">             
             <div class="form-inline">
 ....
```

then I receive an error:

ERROR TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addFormGroup')

And debugging it's happening because there is no parent found for the elements... where it should find the parent form it's null.

I've been trying some solutions found here (with no luck):

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2b3zcz?file=src%2Fapp%2Faddress%2Faddress.component.html



https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewdzmp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent%2Ffamily%2Ffamily.component.ts
```

Comment: You can refer to below link for reactive form in the parent-child component.

https://blog.profanis.me/blog/reactive-forms-in-parent-child-components

Comment: Thanks! The info was clearer in that blog... I had a different scenario but it was really helpful!

Comment: Kindly upvote the comments if you feel really helpful. So that I can get enough reputation.

Comment: Sorry I don't have that option! (???) Maybe you can create an answer... I have a button to vote answers but only a flag for comments.

Comment: Done I have added has answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Jai Saravanan!

In my case I've fixed it this way:

parent html (referring child):

```
<form [formGroup]="Nsfg.invoiceFormGroup">
   <div formGroupName="namespace">
     <fileHeaderComponent formGroupName="FileHeader"></fileHeaderComponent>
```

html child:

```
<div [formGroup]="fileHeaderFormGroup">
```

ts child:

```
export class FileHeaderComponent implements OnInit {      
  @Input() formGroupName: string;

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fileHeaderFormGroup = NsGet.fileHeader as FormGroup;
  }
```

NsGet is equal to

```
 Nsfg.invoiceFormGroup.get('namespace').get('FileHeader');
```